# Gravity operated railroads in a low tech fantasy world?

Tags: engineering, low-fantasy, trains

I'm working on a low tech setting for a fantasy story. I'd like to see how far I can get operating within the laws of physics (no magic, gunpowder, or steam-powered devices) but still produce interesting solutions to engineering problems.

For example, I'm thinking a continent-spanning empire could benefit from a network of rails originating from a capital city in order to quickly move armies to quell rebellions.

Given a proper gradient to overcome friction, could an unpowered railcar starting at high altitude (say a high mountain) roll along a track for hundreds or even thousands of miles without stopping?

Comment: Even if the answer is "yes", how do we get the car back up the hill?

Comment: @Alexander Good question - presumably trains could be hauled back to the capital by animal teams or via canal over many weeks or months.

Comment: As for the question itself - not with the gradient of 1/100 (or smaller) and real world friction. Yes with maglev or similar frictionless technology.

Comment: You might find it worthwhile to read many of the stories set in the universe of Eric Flint's _1632_.

Comment: @Alexander So a train starting at 6 miles altitude (~30,000 feet) would roll for approximately 600 miles down to sea level at a constant gradient slightly steeper than 1/100?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Has Eric Flint created a similar rail system for his books?

Comment: No, but there is a lot of discussion of just what tech is possible with modern _knowledge_ but 1630's _infrastructure_.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I'll take a look - thank you!

Comment: @Alexander I recall seeing that a ball rolling down a brachistochrone-shaped ramp travels farther than a constant ramp, might be possible to squeeze a few hundred more miles out of a gravity train?

Comment: What is your technology level exactly? You have iron/steel works, advanced bearings, and are able to produce enough to build a railroad and some sort of railcar, all industrial revolution inventions, but you're still calling it low tech? And for some reason pulling it with animals isn't an option?

Comment: I am not able to give an exact answer about required gradient, but if you think it's Ok for your story to have a hub city at altitude of 6 miles, it should be Ok to have one-way gravity propelled trains running for 100+ miles from it.

Comment: The underlying question is how there's enough metal for a rail network without having Industrial Revolution level of mining tech (which includes steam powered mine pumps) and ore refining.   AFAIK, historically, wooden rails didn't last very long.   Anyway, it might be worth looking to Sean McMullen's "*Souls in the Great Machine*", which did describe human pedal-powered (!) trains, where both a dedicated crew and, optionally, passengers pedaled to move train cars along a track.

Comment: Do not underestimate man powered things https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draisine

Comment: @Mathaddict The tech level is pre-Industrial Revolution - no steam power. Producing steel is a challenge, but not impossible. Steel was manufactured in quantity during the Song Dynasty in medieval China.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan I like the idea of human or animal powered trains. If this world is like medieval China on steroids, with a population of billions and ample iron resources, I think steel production wouldn't be an issue (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_the_Song_dynasty#Steel_and_iron_industries).

Comment: @Alexander Not necessarily the entire hub city will be located at 30,000 feet - just the rail hub operated by a worker caste that's acclimated to the high altitude. I'll snoop around, there must be a college physics text somewhere that has math problem about how long it takes a train to roll to a stop.

Comment: @RobertF everything that we are sending down in cars (cargo, passengers, army) must somehow get to the hub, unless it's already there. I know you want to limit magic and tech in your world, but maybe the Castle Mount from Robert Silverberg;s [Majipoor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majipoor_series) can serve as a model.

Answer (score 7):

**Your empire can have a network of canals.**

1. No steel needed.
2. A lot more work to cut a canal than a rail.  Ditto for derailing a barge.
3. Animals can pull barges along the canal, like they do.  Bargemen (and women!) can sing songs, sometimes about the animals.  Like the good old mule whose name is Sal.
4. Unpowered barge coming down canal from altitude is much more exciting.  You can cry havoc! and let slip the barges of war.   Maybe there could be cameras to take your picture on the way down.
5. "Warbarge Ascendant" will be the name of the second book in your series because they have to get the war barges up back to the top.

Comment: Locks are a very old technology.

Comment: Thank you - agreed that canals are a proven technology with both animal and wind power. Manufacturing steel in a pre-industrial setting is a big hurdle if rails are to be built. Keep in mind the Song Dynasty of medieval China was more than capable of producing prodigious amounts of iron & steel without steam power. The Chinese Empire is an inspiration here - but turned up to 11. :-)

Comment: Canals are great for shipping goods, however, "quickly move armies" is not something that was done via canals.

Answer (score 1):

One gravity based option would be to have regular stops along the track where a massive weight could be rolled onto the top of a small tower on an "engine" carriage. The weight would force down some sort of connected geared mechanism that drove the wheels. As the weight slowly sank down it would propel the train forward. At the next station the old weight is rolled off and a new one is rolled on much higher up.

Each station would need a means of raising the weights up either by human/animal labour or perhaps aided by water power if available. Long down hill stretches could also be incorporated.

Comment: +1 Very clever, I hadn't thought about using weights to spin up the wheels of the railcars. And it wouldn't have to be a single massive weight that's lifted - a bunch of smaller weights could be lifted using conscripted labor or animal power.

Comment: True. Could even be water if available or it could have a "mixed fuel" capability